# (Dynamic Programming) Variation of weighted interval scheduling

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Hi I have been trying really badly to solve this problem.

Input: Array of Jobs. 
            Each job has: start date, finish date, profit AND a boolean attribute which indicates if that job requires two machines in order for it to be completed.

Output: Maximum Profit

We only have two machines to complete the Jobs. The aim is to choose the Jobs which will produce the max profit.

It is similar to the classic Variation of weighted invterval schedulling problem except for the fact we now have to machines which can work in parallel and that some Jobs require both machines.
The problem must be solved with a Dynamic Programming approach bottom-up.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I am not asking for the solution. I am just asking if someone could tell me a way to approach the problem